# How to add values dynamically in stirng two dimensional array its add values to all index in android

Tags: android

I have a two dimensional array as following:

```
static String[][] arr1 = new String[20][20];
```

I have to add values using,count3 as index value.

```
 arr1[count3 -1][1]=partEdit1.getText().toString();
```

But it add the values to all index,I want to add particular index only.
How to replace the value its like,
arr1[count3 -1][3].replace(arr1[count3 -1][3], partEdit2.getText().toString());
but it doesn't working...please help me..

Comment: If you don't use index value in loop then arr1[2][1] or any array index is the particular index directly............

Comment: im not using loop,just previous and next button to show arr1 values using count3 as index.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how count3 is being used/initialized/modified; or otherwise arr1[][] is being modified somewhere else. It seems very vague at the moment with that question because it seems like your syntax is correct with just those method.